# Android AChartEngine graphicalView share events

Tags: android, callback, scroll, listener, achartengine

First i give my View show below. and give some explanation:[image]

In my ViewGroup i have two GraphicalView, each of them share the same size space. Let's just call the chart above chartA and below one chartB.

Then i have some questions:

1. If i make a move a movement on chartA ,how could i make the chartB move just as my finger moving on chartB?
2. If i pinch on chartA can also chartB change auto?
3. I want to add some callback function to some points? Does ACE supports this?
4. I do not want to show numbers negative while user pinching.How can I make this point?

**Last is my chart code:**

```
mDataset.addSeries(series);
PointStyle style = PointStyle.CIRCLE;
renderer = buildRenderer(lineColor, style, true);
setChartSettings(renderer, "X", "Y", 0, 50, yMin, yMax, Color.WHITE,
                 Color.WHITE, title,chartColor);
GraphicalView chart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, renderer);
layout.addView(chart, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
HashMap map = new HashMap();
```

**and the renderer:**

```
protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildRenderer(int color,
                                                 PointStyle style,
                                                 boolean fill) {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(color);
    r.setPointStyle(style);
    r.setFillPoints(fill);
    r.setLineWidth(3);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    return renderer;
}
```

I random all the data i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to register a `PanListener` on your `chartA` and on every `panApplied` event, just do: `rendererB.setXAxisMin(rendererA.getXAxisMin());` and the same for max X and for the Y axis and then call `chartB.repaint();`
2. Same as the above, just that you need to add a `ZoomListener`.
3. You can set a click listener: `chartA.setOnClickListener();`
4. Please reformulate into a separate question.

Also, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) code showing you how to use the above APIs.